# Normalize negative and positive data in a data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to normalize (in the sense of a Gaussian distribution) 42 numeric variables in a data frame `Data`.  Each variable is either positive or negative.  I want to use `log10(x)` for positive ones and `log10(max(x + 1) - x)` for negative ones.  I need a programmatic way to apply these transformations.

I can apply the transformations to the variables individually.  An example with a positive variable would be `log10(Data$salinity)`.  An example with a negative variable would be `log10(max(Data$depth + 1) - Data$depth)`.

But how can I apply the appropriate transformations programmatically to all 42 variables?

Comment: Data sampled from a distribution with positive skew can take nonpositive values. By "positively skewed", do you just mean "positive"?

Comment: check out dplyr's `across()` used within `mutate()`

Comment: Do you have also character variables or just numeric? Are your negative variables taking only negative values and positive variables only positive values?

Comment: Thank you for the questions, I did not explain it correctly (I corrected it now). By negatively and positively skewed variables, I mean variables with NO-Gausian distribution and mostly negative values and variables with NO-Gausian distribution and mostly positive values, respectively.

Comment: Maybe: `Data[pos] <- lapply(Data[pos], log10)` and `Data[neg] <- lapply(Data[neg], function(x) log10(1 + max(x) - x))`, where `pos` and `neg` are character vectors listing the names of the positive and negative variables, respectively?

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding: "Each variable is either positive or negative."

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **moments** package to easily calculate the skewness of any vector, matrix, or data frame.

```
library(moments)
```

Simulate some data since none was supplied.

```
set.seed(404)
data <- data.frame(matrix(sample(50), 10, 5))
data
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  11  1 50 21 20
2  24 25 17 47  4
3  39 37 38  8  7
4  43 22 45 16 46
5  40 19 44 27 23
6   2 48 33 12 30
7  28 32 29 31 34
8  10 15  6 18 13
9  41 35 42  5  9
10 26 36  3 14 49
```

You can check the skewness values for each column.

```
skewness(data)
        X1         X2         X3         X4         X5 
-0.3840801 -0.4021135 -0.6190580  0.9696532  0.3811696
```

So the first and third columns have negative skewness. Then apply your two functions to each variable conditionally. You didn't say what to do if the skewness was exactly zero. Here I return the column as is.

```
newdata <- data.frame(ifelse(skewness(data)<0, log10(max(data+1) - data), 
                              ifelse(skewness(data)>0, log10(data), data)))

newdata
         X1        X2        X3       X4        X5
1  1.602060 1.6989700 0.0000000 1.322219 1.3010300
2  1.431364 1.4149733 1.5314789 1.672098 0.6020600
3  1.079181 1.1461280 1.1139434 0.903090 0.8450980
4  0.903090 1.4623980 0.7781513 1.204120 1.6627578
5  1.041393 1.5051500 0.8450980 1.431364 1.3617278
6  1.690196 0.4771213 1.2552725 1.079181 1.4771213
7  1.361728 1.2787536 1.3424227 1.491362 1.5314789
8  1.612784 1.5563025 1.6532125 1.255273 1.1139434
9  1.000000 1.2041200 0.9542425 0.698970 0.9542425
10 1.397940 1.1760913 1.6812412 1.146128 1.6901961
```

Comment: This is great for the question as it was, thank you. Just that I meant variables with non-Gausian distribution and negative values or positive values I correct my question. I apologize.

Comment: If you don't want the skewness, then what summary statistic do you want?